# Grails autoImport false for all domains in a plugin

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql

I have a couple of grails projects that are using a 'Common' grails project in the form of a plugin.  Due to domain object name clashes, `autoImport` should be set to `false` for all domain objects in the common project, i.e.

```
class SomeDomain{
    String id
    String value

    static mapping = {
      autoImport false
    }
}
```

Is there a way to change the autoImport default for all domain classes in a plugin project?  I thought about trying to change the dataSource in the Common project, but that won't be preserved when it is used as a plugin.

Comment: I guess you could set your plugin to load before the domain class plugin and change the mapping closure by the MetaClass.

Comment: That is intriguing.  What controls the plugin loading?

Comment: You have `loadBefore` and `loadAfter` attributes that you can declare in your plugin descriptor.

Comment: I ended up simply turning `autoImport` off for each project that uses the Common project.  We have very limited HQL use, so it wasn't worth going through anything too in depth.